# Regex for newline in XML

Tags: xml, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I'm trying desperately hard to figure this out but with no luck. I'm trying to parse this XML data in Postgres:

```
<map>
  <entry>
    <string>id</string>
    <string>555</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>label</string>
    <string>Need This Value</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>748</string>
  </entry>
</map>
```

I'm trying to get the value in the `string` element right after `<string>label</string>`. Note that the Postgres version I'm working does not have the XML (libxml) function installed.

I have tried many variations of:

`substring(xmlStringData from E'<string>label</string>\\n<string>(.*?)</string>')`

but with no luck.

Comment: Why don't you use [`xpath()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) instead?

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, that function is not installed on the Postgres database that I'm working with and I can't simply install it due to it being a production database.

Comment: Regex? Drop them and you'll see the light. You may try to match with two captures (`<string>1</string><string>2</string>`) but XML may be pretty _irregular_ and your regex may work only with a well-defined strict format.

Comment: Hmmm, you pretty much lead me in the right direction by mentioning well-defined strict format

Comment: `the Postgres version I'm working does not have the XML (libxml) function installed.` How about letting us in on the secret, then? What *is* your Postgres version?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I'm working with version 9.0. That version does support XML functions, but the system administrators never installed libxml when they shipped the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seem to got it figured out. I just needed to account for the spaces after the newline. The solution was:

```
substring(event_data from E'<string>label</string>\\n\\s*?<string>(.*?)</string>')
```

Answer (score 2):

[**`xpath()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) would be the right tool here.
Because, you know ...

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

While stuck with your unfortunate situation, this would do the trick:

```
WITH t(x) AS (SELECT '<map>
  <entry>
    <string>id</string>
    <string>555</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>label</string>
    <string>Need This Value</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>748</string>
  </entry>
</map>'::text
)
SELECT substring(x, '<string>label</string>[\s]*?<string>(.*?)</string>')
FROM  t
```

Returns:

```
substring
---------------
Need This Value
```

regexp explained:

`<string>label</string>` .. finds the position
`[\s]`.. whitespace (including `\n` and `\r`)
`*?` .. do this "non-greedy", so ignore whitespace up until ...
`<string>`.. the next string element
`(.*?)` .. capturing parentheses, any characters, non-greedy
`</string>` .. up to the next appearance of the end tag

This is *halfway* reliable, unless you throw in unconventional XML formatting - which is why you should use an XML parser to begin with ...

Answer (score 0):

If your `<entry>` list is not variable. You can use the following regex and access to the capturing group in the 4th match to get the content.

```
<string>(.*?)<\/string>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sF4sO7/1)**

On the other hand, If you want to access at the first match, you can use the following regex:

```
<string>id<\/string>|<string>\d+<\/string>|<string>label<\/string>|<string>(.*?)<\/string>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sF4sO7/2)**

Comment: It seems like the OP wants grab that value immediately instead of having tons of matches to search through.

Comment: @skamazin well, OP didn't specify that but you could be right. I provided another option to do it at the first time. Thanks for let me know that